# Archives widget dropdown to be styled like Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

In WordPress, there is default Archives widget that displays a form select with the list of monthly archives and `on change` executes:

> document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

I need the same functionality but styled like a Bootstrap dropbdown

```
<div class="btn-group dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-link">Dropdown Button</button>
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-large" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Is there any class that I could add to the select, so that I get the Bootstrap dropdown style along with the same functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way of modifying the output for that widget. You have to copy the whole [`WP_Widgets_Archives`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/default-widgets.php#L233) and create your own widget.

See the [Widgets_API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) and this old, but still valid article: [The complete guide to creating widgets in WordPress 2.8](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/05/26/the-complete-guide-to-creating-widgets-in-wordpress-28).

You'll have to place your code in this block:

```
if ( $d ) {
    ?>      
        <div class="btn-group dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-link">Dropdown Button</button>
            <button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-large" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <?php wp_get_archives( array('type' => 'monthly', 'format' => 'html', 'show_post_count' => $c)); ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php
}
```

Note the format `html` for `wp_get_archives`, this produces a `<li>` list.

Comment: Thought it would be simple like passing arguments. I figured out the scrollbar. I'll ask a seperate question only if i can't figure out the header. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SASS

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

.widget_archive select {
  @extend .form-control;
}
```